# FOSS Web-based for employee daily report or journal

Tags: open-source, web-apps, project-management, reporting, human-resources

I'm looking for a free/open-source web-based solution to deploy on-premises that enables my coworkers to write a journal of what they accomplished (and possibly their impediments) so that everyone (especially teammates and managers) get updated about their performance and such and I can use it to extract knowledge later.

I don't want cloud-based solutions. I've already found several like that and they were pretty good but having it on-premises is a must.

I'm thinking of something with features like that of a blogging system or social media platform.

Solutions like confluence are fine but too much specialized. Other HR systems or PM systems have lots of other features that I don't need.

PHP or .Net is preferred. We have a linux cpanel host (only php capable) and a windows IIS VPS accessible from the internet and an ubuntu VPS only accessible via company network which I can setup almost every technology on it. But I prefer it to be accessible from outside so people can use it from home when working remotely or on the go.

Do you recommend anything?

Comment: https://rednotebook.sourceforge.io/ and https://awesomeopensource.com/project/adueck/journee-diary

Comment: @User24601 Nice projects! But I really need something that works on a network not just locally. I found some projects like exo platform but they have too many features. I also found blogin but it's cloud-only and well, not free